# Upload images bigger than 1MB not working

Tags: assets, upload, nginx

I am trying to upload jpg assets to Craft. As long as the files are smaller than **approx. 1MB** it's working, even in bulk upload. As soon as there's a file bigger than 1MB Craft gets stuck like this:

[image]

You can see on the image that files smaller as the 1MB have been uploaded successfully.

The file doesn't show up in the assets directory on the server file system.

I enabled devMode to take a look at the logs but no error level log entry shows up that is related to the upload request. JS console shows no errors as well.

So my question is: What is going on? How can I fix this so I can upload files within the limits I specified in `php.ini`?

**Some info:**
I am using Laravel Forge + DO
Web server: nginx/1.11.5
PHP Ver: 7.1.0
post_max_size = 14M
upload_max_filesize = 12M

PS: I say approx. 1MB because I was able to test with files that are roughly below/above 1MB file size.

**Update**
I noticed Imagemagick was not installed. After installation: no difference. I even disabled GD: no difference.

Comment: Did you check that the settings has been applied, and did you check server logs?

Comment: @FredCarlsen Yes the settings are showing up in Crafts PHPinfo. Which logs do you mean by server logs?

Comment: @FredCarlsen Man I got it. You pointed me to look inside `/var/log/nginx/domain-error.log`. It says: `client intended to send too large body`

Comment: I assume that it's returning a 500 error, so I'd make sure devMode is turned on. Then I would check phperrors.log, craft.log and any other relevant logs.

Comment: Right, is that a limit in nginx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx's setting `client_max_body_size` was set to its default value of `1M` because it was not specified after provisioning the DO server with Laravel Forge. Weird thing is just that the user doesn't get any response.

**Solution:** Set `client_max_body_size` to something higher or 0 in your Nginx config file.

[image]